# Power BI. Using the SUMMARIZE function in a MAXX

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have table with Sales. All Sales divide between Men and Women. I need to find out who have the biggest count of sales, men or woman.
I have tried using Summarize and MAXX together, but sonething is wrong.

```
MAXX(SUMMARIZE(
    'public Brand',
    'public Brand'[Возрастная группа],
    "Свод",
    COUNT('public Brand'[Id]))
```

Comment: can you add some sample data please?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correct, you need a single output "Men" OR "Women" based on the count sales count/amount. For example, if there are total 10 count or row for Men and 12 for Women, you need Women as output from the measure. I prepared a very simple data set for example (Excel part in the image) to calculate the measure. You can see the final output in the red marked box.

[image]

Here below is the Measure Code-

> For most number of sales number

```
Gender With Most Count = 
VAR Gourp_by_gender_with_count = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        Sales, 
        Sales[Gender], 
        "GenderCount", COUNT(Sales[Gender])
    )

VAR max_count_among_gender_group = 
MAXX (
    TOPN(1,Gourp_by_gender_with_count,[GenderCount],DESC),
    [Gender]
)

RETURN max_count_among_gender_group
```

> For most number of sales amount

```
Gender With Most Sales Amount = 
VAR Gourp_by_gender_with_amount = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        Sales, 
        Sales[Gender], 
        "GenderWiseSales", SUM(Sales[Amount])
    )

VAR max_amount_among_gender_group = 
MAXX (
    TOPN(1,Gourp_by_gender_with_amount,[GenderWiseSales],DESC),
    [Gender]
)

RETURN max_amount_among_gender_group
```